# Write data to Word document using Apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi, aes, fileoutputstream, xwpf

I am implementing AES Algorithm 128 bit key. After encryption, the first 16 bytes of encrypted data will be stored in a .docx file. After that the .docx file will be blocked.

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument() ;
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename,true);//filename is .docx word document
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
run.setText(ress1);//ress1 is a String datatype
document.write(out);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked"? What exact issue are you facing?

Comment: when I opened .docx file It shows:The office open XML files cannot be opened beacause there are problems with the contents.After that it shows :Word found unreadable content in word doucument.Do you want to recover the contents of this document?

Comment: How did you figured that first 16 bytes of data is stored and remaining data is not stored ? Also I am a bit curious about why you want to store encrypted data on word file? Are you trying to password protect your file?

Comment: I have print the result in program after every round.I have seen the result in command prompt.so i came to know that first 16 bytes of data is stored.

Comment: when I am encrypting the .docx file.is it necessary to store the encrypted data on word file?

Comment: Check my updated answer. You can encrypt your .docx file using that code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

As per what I understand from your comment, you want to encrypt your word file. You can achieve that using following code snippet:

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs, EncryptionMode.agile);

Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
enc.confirmPassword(<your_password>);


OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File(<file_path>), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE); //opening package for encryption 
OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs); //perform encryption 
opc.save(os); //save package
opc.close();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file_path"); 
fs.writeFilesystem(fos); //write the file back to file system
fos.close();
```

Comment: I have added above lines sir.but there is no change sir.

Comment: for example first String is dc3ae4d253f5620ec05848ff8847696d. This string was stored in .docx file.after that so many strings are generating.but word document did not append those strings to the first string.only first String was stored in .docx file.